# spring cloud config refresh cache configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, caffeine

Considering the below service how can I dynamically modify the cache configuration with the **/actuator/refresh** endpoint

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class GreetingService {

    @Cacheable("greeting")
    public String greet(String name) {
       log.info("Greeting: {}", name);
       return "Hello " + name ;
    }
}
```

with the following default configuration

```
spring
  cache:
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=100,expireAfterAccess=600s
```

Let's say setting to **maximumSize=50,expireAfterAccess=300s**

Adding **@RefreshScope** in **GreetingService** does not work. Somehow I need to instruct Spring Boot to re-create the CacheManager?

I have a supporting project here:

1. https://github.com/altfatterz/refreshscope-demo
2. https://github.com/altfatterz/refreshscope-demo-config

Thanks.

Comment: Caffeine does support dynamically updating the [configuration](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Policy), if that helps. This can only modify already enabled features and probably isn't exposed in Spring's support.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You are using actuator so probably you have also [cache actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#caches) present. So for your case test with this command:
`curl 'http://server:port/actuator/caches/greeting' -i -X DELETE`

note: I didn't tested that, it's just an idea

Comment: yes, that is correct, but I wanted to check if with the @RefreshScope it will work or not if there are cache configuration changes